# "argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments" keeps happening when running a mediation analysis

Tags: r, regression

When running mediate analysis, I intermittently encounter this error. What could be the reason? It doesn't happen consistently. However, once it occurs, it keeps happening.
Could it be that the file variable is not being read properly?

```
> me.out1 <- mediate(y ="physical", m ="psychological", x ="stress", data = subdata)
> Error in mediate(y = "physical", m = "psychological", x = "stress",  : 
> argument 2 matches multiple formal arguments
```

Thanks.

I suspected that the presence of Korean characters in the variable might be causing issues with reading the file name, so I executed the following code.

```
data<-read.csv("02. 분석데이터\\02. stress요인 추가 데이터(n=813)-CP949.csv", encoding="CP949", fileEncoding ="CP949")
```

Comment: Where is this function `mediate()` from? Please include any packages you are using

Comment: also please include your data by dput(subdata)

Comment: @hanol-kim is it right to assume that ```mediate()``` is from the ```mediation``` package?

Comment: I used packages below

install.packages("mediation")
install.packages("psych")
library("psych")
library("mediation")

Comment: `mediation::mediate` has parameters `model.m`, `model.y` and `mediator`.  So when you write `m = "psychological"`, R doesn't know which one of the three you mean.  You need to write enough of the parameter name so that it is unique amongst the possibilities, so `model.m`, `model.y` or `me` (or more in the last case).